# how to intercept parameter with mockito for a normal array of objects?

Tags: java, mocking, mockito

This might sound like a very easy question but I am really struggling to archive the solution.

Normally I mock and match quite easily my arguments.

Now I am matching a method that is like this:

```
getAppFacebookClient(page, V2_11).publish(destination, JsonObject.class, parameters.asArray());
```

this is for a facebook application and the parameters is a list of a custom Object. the asArray[] method was created in the class and basically does something like this:

```
public Parameter[] asArray() {
        return parameters.toArray(new Parameter[parameters.size()]);
    }
```

and the Parameter of this return is of the type `com.restfb.Parameter`

So, I am basically doing this

`when(client.publish(anyString(), eq(JsonObject.class), any(com.restfb.Parameter[].class))).thenReturn(result)`;

but seems like it is never taken and of course I cannot manipulate result,

Any idea how could I mock this kind of objects in a proper way?

I also tried the other way

```
doReturn(result).when(client).publish(anyString(), eq(JsonObject.class), any(com.restfb.Parameter[].class));
```

Comment: How does the `publish` method signature look like?

Comment: like this String connection, Class<T> objectType, Parameter... parameters

Comment: Vararg then! See the answer below. The typical matcher does not work then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is correct ... unless the `publish` uses varargs!

In such a case you need to use `any()` / `anyVararg()` matcher.

Consider:

```
@Mock Thingy testee;

interface Thingy {
    int f(String... arg);
}

@Test
public void test() {
    // given
    // works only if signature is `f(String[] arg)`
    // when(this.testee.f(Mockito.any(String[].class))).thenReturn(42);
    when(this.testee.f(Mockito.any())).thenReturn(42); // anyVararg() is deprecated

    // when
    final int result = this.testee.f(new String[] { "hello", "world" });

    // then
    assertThat(result, comparesEqualTo(42));
    // works only if signature is `f(String[] arg)`
    // verify(this.testee).f(Mockito.any(String[].class));
    verify(this.testee).f(Mockito.any());
}
```